# "-bash: fork: retry: ..." on SSH connection

Tags: centos, ssh, bash

When I'm connecting via ssh to my useraccount of my server, I'm getting the following error:

```
    -bash: fork: retry: No child processes
    -bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Does anyone has an idea whats causing this error ? It's possible that it's just a little thing, but I don't find any solution.

Thank you.

[my os: CENTOS 7.2 x86_64]

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to log in as root?

Comment: No, root login via ssh works without error.

Comment: In that case log in as root to find out how many processes the problematic user has running.

Comment: Thank you, this was the right hint. I had to stop a docker container.